# Высота блока 100% если у родительского высота указанна в min-height

Tags: html, css, css3

Если у родительского блока указана высота в `min-height`, каким образом может наследовать эту высоту дочерний блок?

`height: 100%` у дочернего блока не дает желаемого результата, при изменении `position`, тоже есть сложности, в частности с падингами (да можно сделать `height: calc(100% - 10px);`), но почему то мне кажется что это решение похожее на костыль. Можно ли как то сделать это более лаконично?

```css
.container{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.parent-flex-el{
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width:100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;  
}
.flex-el{
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.child-flex-el{
  width: 100%;  
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  height: 20px;
}
/*-------*/
.fixed-h{
  height: 200px;
 }
.min-h{
  min-height: 200px;
 }
.position{
  position: relative; 
}
.position > *{
  position:absolute;  
  width: 100%;
}
.h-calc > *{
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
}
.fl{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.fl > *{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>height: 200px;</p>
  <div class="parent-flex-el fixed-h">
    <div class="flex-el">
      <div class="child-flex-el">one</div>
      <div class="child-flex-el">two</div>
      <div class="child-flex-el">three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>min-height: 200px;</p>
  <div class="parent-flex-el min-h">
    <div class="flex-el">
      <div class="child-flex-el">one</div>
      <div class="child-flex-el">two</div>
      <div class="child-flex-el">three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>position: absolute;</p>
  <div class="parent-flex-el min-h position">
    <div class="flex-el">
      <div class="child-flex-el">one</div>
      <div class="child-flex-el">two</div>
      <div class="child-flex-el">three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>height: calc();</p>
  <div class="parent-flex-el min-h position h-calc">
    <div class="flex-el">
      <div class="child-flex-el">one</div>
      <div class="child-flex-el">two</div>
      <div class="child-flex-el">three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>flex</p>
  <div class="parent-flex-el min-h fl">
    <div class="flex-el">
      <div class="child-flex-el">one</div>
      <div class="child-flex-el">two</div>
      <div class="child-flex-el">three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Использовать flex.

Comment: @Qwertiy родитель flex и flex-flow:column nowrap , а дочерний align-self:stretch?

Comment: @Qwertiy, flex не помог

Comment: Значит не так использовал...

Comment: @Qwertiy Возможно, в вопросе дополнил пример, где мог ошибиться?

Comment: Не на тот элемент повесил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать родительский блок `flex`ом, а дочерний растянуть по ширине.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.parent-flex-el {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.flex-el {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child-flex-el {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  height: 20px;
}

/*-------*/

.min-h {
  min-height: 200px;
}

.fl {
  display: flex;
}

.fl>* {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>flex</p>
  <div class="parent-flex-el min-h fl">
    <div class="flex-el">
      <div class="child-flex-el">one</div>
      <div class="child-flex-el">two</div>
      <div class="child-flex-el">three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```